# using cheerio to select nested nodes

Tags: node.js, xml, cheerio

**update:** I figured it out. See answer below

I have an xml like so, and I want to select `a[type="foo"] d`. I am using `cheerio`. I have gotten as far as `d = $('a[type=foo]')` but am lost after that.

```
<a type="foo">
    <b>
        <c>
            <d blah="fop" bung="frum">
                <e>Lorem Dramam</e>
            </d>
            <f>sp. cr.</f>
        </c>
    </b>
    <b box="[4,7,18,22]" from="31" to="32">
        urn:foo:bar:baz
        <g box="[2,9,10,12]" code="AC" from="31" to="32">AC</g>
        crummy 
        <h box="[7,12,22,30]" country="Nigeria">A</h>
        winter
    </b>
</a>
```

**Answer:** `const d = $('a[type=foo] d')` does the job

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following the jQuery selection paradigm, `const d = $('a[type=foo] d')` does the job